# Using JS to remove elements but having remaining space filled in

Tags: javascript, html, css

As an educational experience, I have been playing around with JavaScript on different websites.

I wanted to try to use JavaScript to remove the entire right bar but to also have the rest of the body text fill in the space received from removing the bar.

However, I am only successful in removing the right bar, but the rest of the page does not fill in the new missing space. Can I do this with just using the JavaScript console?

Website: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/

JS code:

```
child = document.getElementById("content-related");
child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't yet, get familiar with the developer tools of your browser (Generally you can bring them up using the `F12` key). This will allow you to try commands in a console as well as view the elements on the page.

If you view the hierarchy, there is a div with id of `columnwrap` that contains `content-main` and `content-related`. Your command works correctly and removes the element, but if you view the `content-main` element in the dev tools you'll see that it is set to `70%` width so it doesn't reflow and take up the rest of the space.

You can reset the width of the `content-main` element by setting it's width to either `100%` or `auto`.

```
document.getElementById('content-main').style = 'width: 100%';
document.getElementById('content-main').style = 'width: auto';
```

Answer (score 1):

The `content-main` div is set to 70% of the total width.

Add either this line

```
document.getElementById('content-main').setAttribute('width', '100%');
```

or this one

```
document.getElementById('content-main').style = 'width:auto';
```

Comment: `auto` might be better sometimes
Edit: Not on this case, but in some too tight layouts where things can go off if position: absolute or floats are around

Answer (score 1):

Check the CSS. The attribute width of #content-main is 70%.

In order to fill the whole space:

```
document.getElementById("content-main").style.width = '100%';
```